How can you define explicit type "or" logic better than the combination of unions + never?
In the following setup:
export interface BaseMenuItem { title: string; icon: string; }

export interface ComponentMenuItem extends BaseMenuItem { component: any; }

export interface ClickMenuItem extends BaseMenuItem { click: any; }

export type MenuItem = ComponentMenuItem | ClickMenuItem;

const myMenuItem: MenuItem = { title: 'blah', icon: 'blah2', click: true, component: true, }

You would not get a compilation error on myMenuItem. The union allows for properties of each of the type to merge in this way.
However you could truly intend for MenuItem to be either a ComponentMenuItem or a ClickMenuItem. This would follow the line of thinking that that if you tried to instantiate an object of either type on their own without this union it would fail compilation if you added a property of the other, say ClickMenuItem type with a 'component' property.
The only way with still using the union I am currently aware of is the following method:
...
export interface ComponentMenuItem extends BaseMenuItem {
  component: any;
  click?: never; // Ensure click is not present
}

export interface ClickMenuItem extends BaseMenuItem {
  click: any;
  component?: never; // Ensure component is not present
}
...

However overtime with many union types or many unique properties in each of the unioned types this would cause maintenance frustrations or at the very least ugly and unclear code (never's polluting the type definitions of each of the unioned types).
If the type was going to be used for parameters of a function of course you could just overload and make a signature for each type distinctly but that is not always the case.
Is there a more dynamic (not relying on you to manually keep updating the 'nevers') and cleaner way to accomplish this?

Are you possibly looking for ExclusifyUnion from this answer? So type MenuItem = ExclusifyUnion< ComponentMenuItem | ClickMenuItem | ⋯> as shown in this playground link? If so I could write up an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz No I think you got it right - and thanks for replying. That question was from 2017 and phrased more in trying to understand the why (though I know the answers seemed to instead suggest how to get around it). I was hoping that maybe in all my searching there would be a new clean/built-in way to do this. But it seems so far still you can either put in that, in my opinion, complex ExclusifyUnion type or the ts-essentials XOR. Both have intellisense feedback that could be better.

If you think ExclusifyUnion is complex, you should look at the definition of XOR in ts-essentials.

@jcalz Complex versus the simplicity of how built in union is from an end-user perspective - meaning if one were to not just take it at its descriptive name and peak at it it is in a different league than "|". Thanks for linking the duplicate and pointing me to ExclusifyUnion - hopefully something can come of a native support to this.

As an update for anyone who somehow stumbles upon this in the future the ExactType suggestion for TS may be of interest to you: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936
